# ASP.NET MVC 4 - Specified cast is not valid

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a model class and at the top, I have this int defined:

```
 public int AppForms { get; set; }
```

but when I try to assign data to it from a SQlDataReader, the value I am trying to assign is a bit of 1 or 0. I have tried the following with and got the errors below what I have tried.

```
airportItems.AppForms = dataReader.GetValue(26);
Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

airportItems.AppForms = (int)dataReader.GetValue(26);
Specified cast is not valid.
```

What am doing wrong?

airportItems is

```
var airportItems = new AirportClass();
```

and dataReader is

```
SqlDataReader dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();
```

where I am trying to set the value is inside a while loop

```
while (dataReader.Read())
```

Comment: For debugging purposes, see what `dataReader.GetValue(26).GetType()` gives you.  Also, getting values by column index is hard to read, using the column name instead would promote readability.

Comment: What if you use Convert.ToInt32(dataReader.GetValue(26)) ?

Comment: @Matthew using column indexes can dramatically improve performance in large, tight loops.  I would, however, look up the index from the column name outside the loop and use that rather than hard-coding the index number.

Comment: `SqlDataReader.GetValue()` returns a `bool` for `bit` type columns.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite possible based on this that the item at index 26 is not an int, or may actually be null.  You'd have to first check for null before you cast to an int (null is DbNull type).  You can first do:

```
if (!dataReader.IsDBNUll(26))
```

To make sure it's not null, then cast.

Answer (score 0):

`SqlDataReader.GetValue()` returns a `bool` for `bit` type columns.

Please try:

```
public bool AppForms { get; set; }

airportItems.AppForms = !dataReader.IsDBNUll(26) && (bool)dataReader.GetValue(26);
```

Or:

```
public bool AppForms { get; set; }

airportItems.AppForms = !dataReader.IsDBNUll(26) && dataReader.GetBoolean(26);
```